# How to OFF Admon for specific URL in Android WebView

Tags: android, facebook, webview, admob

I have a `WebView` App and in `WebView` I have "Login with Facebook" Button that also open in `WebView`. When someone click "Login with Facebook" then it redirect to facebook.com and ask for Email & Password. I want when user redirect to facebook.com then admob OFF and did not show ad banners. Screenshot:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4QnN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check which link is loading in your web view and if it is facebook login URL, then you can hide the banner view by making it's visibility GONE or INVISIBLE. Something like this:

```
mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I think it may help you...